# Dynamic Runtime Move/Resize rectangle in c#.net

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there anyway to create custom/user controls for rectangle by override their properties , to achieve run time re-size and re-locate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643639/move-a-rectangle-around-a-canvas

Comment: @gabba: As far as I can see is your answer/link about WPF not winforms.

Answer (score 6):

You can check out these CodeProject articles:

- [Move controls on a form at runtime](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31840/Move-controls-on-a-form-at-runtime)
- [Runtime resizable controls](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13184/Runtime-resizable-controls)

Comment: is it possible to resize and relocate the usercontrol at runtime

Comment: yes it is, if answer is accepted you should click on TICK under the answer point to make it green

Comment: Its useful . But it ain't i am looking for exactly .

Comment: what do you need exactly. i will be happy to solve the challenge :)


@Groo: Tnx for edit and sorry for my mistake ;)

Comment: thanks for your support @Maziar , I need exactly like VisualBasic Power Packs Rectangle Shape at Design Time . In design time you can drag and resize those shapes but in runtime can't . Thats what i am looking for ...

Comment: @Dj: but you tag C# and winform

Comment: Yep ... I want them in c# winform .